# Why does Task Scheduler NOT re-run successfully completed tasks

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, task-scheduler

I am using Task Scheduler on Windows 2008 x64. I have 3 tasks, running every night on different times without overlapping. It works for some days - usually 2-3 up to 10 (it's really random), then it stops running the tasks. When I look at the history, I see that the tasks **completed successfully**. In the UI, the column "Next Run Time" stays empty. The tasks are set to run on background; the account for running them is a domain one - it is valid and enabled. When I check with Process Explorer, there are no left-over processes associated with my tasks. I am completely baffled at what's going on.

Comment: Can you post more information about the tasks? Do they write logs and do this logs indicate any problems?

Comment: Agreed, more details are needed - there are a lot of task options in 2008 that can cause a task to expire or just not run in certain instances. There is also a "history" log for each task that could prove helpful.

Comment: It appears that the problem has nothing to do with the TS itself. Rather we had a problem with out domain controller. We fixed the DC and everything works now. Thanks for your replies!

Comment: Teo. I'm also facing on the same issue. The "Next Run Time" column of the scheduled task get empty in random and the task do not execute. Would you please let me know more in details about the problem with your DC and how you fix it? Thanks,
Terence

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft hotfixed this issue recently:

["Next Run Time" value of some scheduled tasks is missing after you restart a computer that is running Windows Vista or Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2619548)

It worked for me.